# Send auto email programmatically

Tags: android, email

i want to send email programmatically.

i tried out the following code.

> final Intent emailIntent = new Intent(
>                 android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
>
> ```
>   emailIntent.setType("plain/text");
>
>   emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL,
>           new String[] { "abc@gmail.com" });
>
>   emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT,
>           "Email Subject");
>
>   emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,
>           "Email Body");
>
>   startActivity(Intent.createChooser(
>           emailIntent, "Send mail..."));
> ```

but problem is that before sending email the application open the activity

[image]

i want to send email directly without open compose activity. how this possible?

Comment: why dont you try __startActivityforResult__ stuff?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Sending Email in Android using JavaMail API without using the default/built-in app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2020088/sending-email-in-android-using-javamail-api-without-using-the-default-built-in-a)

Answer (score 4):

Referred link has correct answer, but there are written **some libraries** to make your **work easy**.

- https://github.com/yesidlazaro/GmailBackground
- https://github.com/thegenuinegourav/Android-Email-App-using-Javamail-Api
- https://github.com/prashantwosti/BackgroundMailLibrary

So don't write all code again, just use any of these library and get your work done in little time.

Answer (score 1):

Sending email programmatically with Kotlin.

- simple email sending, not all the other features (like attachments).
- TLS is always on
- Only 1 gradle email dependency needed also.

I also found this list of email POP services really helpful:

https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/pop-and-imap-email-settings-for-outlook-8361e398-8af4-4e97-b147-6c6c4ac95353

How to use:

```
    val auth = EmailService.UserPassAuthenticator("yourUser", "yourPass")
    val to = listOf(InternetAddress("to@email.com"))
    val from = InternetAddress("from@email.com")
    val email = EmailService.Email(auth, to, from, "Test Subject", "Hello Body World")
    val emailService = EmailService("yourSmtpServer", 587)

    GlobalScope.launch { // or however you do background threads
        emailService.send(email)
    }
```

The code:

```
import java.util.*
import javax.mail.*
import javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress
import javax.mail.internet.MimeBodyPart
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMultipart

class EmailService(private var server: String, private var port: Int) {

    data class Email(
        val auth: Authenticator,
        val toList: List<InternetAddress>,
        val from: Address,
        val subject: String,
        val body: String
    )

    class UserPassAuthenticator(private val username: String, private val password: String) : Authenticator() {
        override fun getPasswordAuthentication(): PasswordAuthentication {
            return PasswordAuthentication(username, password)
        }
    }

    fun send(email: Email) {
        val props = Properties()
        props["mail.smtp.auth"] = "true"
        props["mail.user"] = email.from
        props["mail.smtp.host"] = server
        props["mail.smtp.port"] = port
        props["mail.smtp.starttls.enable"] = "true"
        props["mail.smtp.ssl.trust"] = server
        props["mail.mime.charset"] = "UTF-8"
        val msg: Message = MimeMessage(Session.getDefaultInstance(props, email.auth))
        msg.setFrom(email.from)
        msg.sentDate = Calendar.getInstance().time
        msg.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, email.toList.toTypedArray())
//      msg.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.CC, email.ccList.toTypedArray())
//      msg.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.BCC, email.bccList.toTypedArray())
        msg.replyTo = arrayOf(email.from)

        msg.addHeader("X-Mailer", CLIENT_NAME)
        msg.addHeader("Precedence", "bulk")
        msg.subject = email.subject

        msg.setContent(MimeMultipart().apply {
            addBodyPart(MimeBodyPart().apply {
                setText(email.body, "iso-8859-1")
                //setContent(email.htmlBody, "text/html; charset=UTF-8")
            })
        })
        Transport.send(msg)
    }

    companion object {
        const val CLIENT_NAME = "Android StackOverflow programmatic email"
    }
}
```

Gradle:

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'com.sun.mail:android-mail:1.6.4'
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:1.3.3"
}
```

AndroidManifest:

```
<uses-permission name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Answer (score 0):

It might be an easiest way-

```
    String recipientList = mEditTextTo.getText().toString();
    String[] recipients = recipientList.split(",");

    String subject = mEditTextSubject.getText().toString();
    String message = mEditTextMessage.getText().toString();

    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, recipients);
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, subject);
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, message);

    intent.setType("message/rfc822");
    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Choose an email client"));
```