# Android sending mail from a specific account

Tags: android, email, exchange-server, activesync

I have Exchange ActiveSync setup on my phone and it works as expected. My problem is that when I want to send an email in code it always uses the Gmail account (which of course I cannot remove) as the sender. It is essential that the account used be the Exchange one as that is the users business email account.

I used the code from [Send auto email programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4668871/send-auto-email-programmatically)

It works fine but uses the Gmail account. I have set the Exchange ActiveSync account as the default but it makes no difference.
The application is used in a corporate environment only.

Answer (score 0):

You can go ahead and clear defaults from Manage Apps screen in Settings. That should solve ur problem.

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same issue in my project. There is a small bug in the referenced code.

The first line should read

```
emailIntent.setType("text/plain");
```

instead of

```
emailIntent.setType("plain/text");
```

This fixed it for me.
Hope this helps.