# sending an email automaticlly

Tags: android

I have using some examples on this site to create an email class for sending a CSV file out to an email. It works find, sends the file correctly

The last line in the code reads

```
context.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "Send mail..."));
```

This as far as I understand opens the email app and lets the user send the email. I was looking to see if it was possible to send the email automatically. ie without going to the email client and not leaving my app

Thanks for your time

Comment: Has been asked and answered over here: [Sending email in Android using Javamail API][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2020088/sending-email-in-android-using-javamail-api-without-using-the-default-android-app/2033124#2033124

Comment: try this: http://lovingandroid.blogspot.com/2011/07/gmail-client.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sending mail using the javamail-api

see this post

[Send auto email programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4668871/send-auto-email-programmatically/4668924#4668924)

[Sending Email in Android using JavaMail API without using the default/built-in app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2020088/sending-email-in-android-using-javamail-api-without-using-the-default-android-app/2033124#2033124)