# Android Programing: send mail with html5 page having data and canvas controls

Tags: c#, android, web-services

I am working on android application and I have integrated some of reports in html5 page with canvas controls. I have loaded the data from android database on html5 page using jquery and prepared some charts. Now I have to send this html5 page with dynamic data and canvas controls in mail.

If this is not possible in android then I can use another option to do this from dot net, c# web service, hosted on server. Android application will send request to web service to do the same job. But again here I need help to do the same from web service.

My over all requirements to send html5 page with dynamic data and canvas controls that is loaded by jquery and json.

Please help.

Comment: "My over all requirements to send html5 page with dynamic data and canvas controls that is loaded by jquery and json" -- what makes you think that any mail clients can handle this sort of email message?

Answer (score 0):

You can't (by design) send email from a webpage.

You need to find (=program) a way to render the page with the (dynamic) data that the user is viewing to the body of an email and send it with the email-intend on android.
see: [Send auto email programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4668871/send-auto-email-programmatically)